# How to call `connect` from the same component which has `Provider` context to import redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I used to have `Provider` context wrapped around my top React component: `App`. I then decided to move the context directly to `ReactDOM.render` so that I can use redux `connect` in `App`. I want to use `connect` so that I can use a loader (`LinearProgress`) as the top component in my app. So I will import `loading` from props and display a loader accordingly (`loading` could be toggled from some inner component).

However I keep getting this error:

`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

The page is still rendered normally but I have the above error in the console. I checked the line which causes the error is the following one (inside `App`):

`{loading && <LinearProgress color='secondary'/>}`

If I remove the line then no errors are reported in the console. Why conditional display of loader inside `App` causes the error?

This is the code of the `App` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SearchAppBar from './components/layout/MaterialHeader.js';
import AppInfo from './components/appOperations/AppInfo.js';
import About from './components/layout/About.js';

import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import constants from './constants';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          {loading && <LinearProgress color='secondary'/>}
          <SearchAppBar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" />
            <Route exact path={constants.CLIENT_ROUTES.APP} component={AppInfo}/>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.app.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

This is the code of the parent and top-most component of `App`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import App from './App';
import MaterialBlueTheme from './components/layout/MaterialBlueTheme.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './store.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={MaterialBlueTheme}>
      <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Can you post your `LinearProgress` component here ? Probably issue is there itself.

Comment: `LinearProgress` comes from here: https://material-ui.com/api/linear-progress/

Answer (score 0):

Look for a one of your components that is trying to change the state within the render method. You can't do this:

```
render() {
  this.setState({
    ...
  });

  return (...);
}
```